# permission issue when uploading via php to a folder on my local drive

Tags: php, file-permissions

i've created a folder in my c drive (c:/artwork) that im using to upload files via a form in php, like this:

```
<input name="file" type="file">
```

The problem is that when files are uploaded and i go to the folder and try to open a file i get the following message:
Photo Gallery can't open this picture because yu do not have permission to access the file location

If i manually copy and paste a picture in that same folder, there are no issues. I can open and view pictures perfectly!

Im guessing it has to be a permission issue when uploading via php, but wich? How do i fix it?

Thanks

edit (added code)

```
$destination = 'c:/public_html/discography/artwork/'; // path to the upload folder

if (is_dir($destination) && is_writable($destination)) {
    // if file already exists, ask what to do

    // upload the file  
    $ok = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destination . $_FILES['file']['name']);

    // if file uploaded, go ahead an insert record in database
    if ($ok) {
        $stmt = $conn->stmt_init(); // initialize a prepared statement

        $stmt->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $_FILES['file']['name']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->free_result(); // free the database resources for other queries

        // if success
        if ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) {
            $success = true;
        } else {
            $err_msg = $stmt->error;
        }

        $stmt->close(); // close statement  
    }

} else {
    $err_msg = "'$destination' must be a valid, writable directory!";
}
```

Comment: Which user is running Apache / IIS? Probably the files are being uploaded with read / write access only on the server user / group. If that is the case, all you need to do is make your user a member of the sever group.

Comment: im running apache/mysql/php on my local development environment

Comment: @NullUserException:  i've added the code (is is not finished thought)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you haven't setup "upload_tmp_dir" directives in php.ini then the files are being saved in temp folder. In your case C:\Windows\Temp if you are using IIS and therefore it inherits the permission of that directory instead of c:/public_html/discography/artwork/.

To fix that either set the permission of Temp directory of define a another place to store tmp files in php.ini.

Comment: that was it!!! i knew about the uploads beeing saved in the windows tmp folder, i just didn't realize that the uploaded file inherit the permission settings of the tmp windows folder... I've changed it to:  upload_tmp_dir = "C:\public_html\tmp"  and it works perfectly! many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[chmod()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)** to modify the permissions of that file.

Comment: isn't there a way to do it manually, like i do via ftp on the servers folder instead of doing it with php ?

Comment: The majority of FTP clients will allow you to change the permissions, assuming you have the permissions to do so.  If your client doesn't allow it, then it's time to find something else.

Comment: i agree! but my question was about permissions issues with my c:/ drive and why i can access my uploaded folder but i can't watch the pictures

Comment: If your FTP client allows for local browsing then you should also be able to change the permissions through the client.